# The ellipsis '...' value is not the right color

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 dots '...' at the end of each line when necessary (text overflow). I used the ellipsis value of the text-overflow property. It works: when the window is resized, the '...' are showed but I have 2 problems when the line in my table contains a span:

- the '...' are colored in the font color of the span
- the '...' are resized the size of the font of the span

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah4DR/1/

Maybe this is a novice question but I searched for a time and not found any solution.

I forgot to say that this don't works on **Internet Explorer** but works fine on Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: what browser is this on?  Looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: "Works fine in FF8". Make sure to indicate which browser(s) is(/are) affected!

Comment: @bozdoz, pst: Sorry I forgot to mention the problem occured in internet Explorer!

Comment: @Bronzato "Works fine in IE9". Be more specific :)

Comment: pst: in IE9 when I navigate to http://jsfiddle.net/Ah4DR/1/ and I resize the window smaller I see the second line of the table with '...' colored in yellow. This is my problem. I need this ... colored in Black.

Comment: Oh, wow, they really are there... and very small... and very hard-to-see-yellow. No idea. Best of luck though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It certainly seems to be a bug in IE. It is (for whatever reason) reading the color of first element (or maybe it is the first content) to determine the color of the ellipsis. However, I did find a "work around" for the bug. I would recommend if possible setting this up in some way to just target IE (and only the `td` elements you are using `text-overflow` on), but as a proof of concept, this fixes it:

```
td:before {content: ''; color: black;}
```

Apparently the first `td` content that is defining the color need not be real content, because the pseudo content worked.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem; while my text was white on dark-grey, the ellipsis color seemed to be black. I solved it by simply setting the color of the  that contained the text-overflow: ellipsis, like this:

```
.ellipsis-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 154px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: white;       /* --> ellipsis color */
}
```